# click row in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

hiiiiiiiii
I am trying to do the following :
I have a gridview and I want to fire a function(C# function) when I click over the row (any where)
this my code :

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    string alertBox = "alert('";
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        alertBox +=e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
        alertBox += "')";
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", alertBox);
    }
}
public void test()
{
    Response.Write("ffff");
}
```

this is working ..and every time I click over the gridview
I found  an alert ...but I want
to fire C# function(like test function in the code)
how to do that
thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can emulate GridView command (for example 'SelectCommand') then catch [RowCommand event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) and call your method.
Like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
...
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:__doPostBack('" + GridView1.ClientID + "','SelectCommand$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString() + "')")
...
}

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "SelectCommand") {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks Tadas
I have tried your code
but the (GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged) doesn't fire at all
can you help me again

Comment: So, I was a little bit wrong :). Better emulate a custom command, not Select. See my answer. But my previous suggestion should work too. Try to add javascript: before __doPostBack().

Comment: thanks Tadas ... I think I am too close t achive it
but it didn't worked for the time bieng
you said I have to catch the rowcommand event...
I tried to do that from the propirties pane of the gridview
(that's what you are talking about ???)
more help please

Comment: Hmm, I don't know. When you click a row do you get postback?

Answer (score 0):

Make your changes in client script or initiate a postback to the server to run the server method.

Comment: OK I agree but how to initiate  a post back 
can you explain more??

Answer (score 0):

To execute a code-behind method with a postback you would have to manually initiate a postback. Essentially you would be wiring up your own event outside of the GridView control because the "RowClick" event doesn't exist - See Tadas' answer.

Alternatively you could execute the code-behind method without a postback. You could use an Ajax callback. See Ajax Page Methods in ASP.Net.